# Unable to dynamically set focus in WPF MVVM application

Tags: wpf, mvvm, focus

I'm working on a WPF application using the MVVM pattern, and I have hit a problem with focus.

I have full screen slide on 'overlays' and within each overlay I have a ContentPresenter that I use to display arbitrary view models/views by data binding it's content to a view model property I set in my data context, like so:

```
<Grid Name="OverlayContainer"
      FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True"
      KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
      IsEnabled="False">

  <Grid.RenderTransform>
    <TranslateTransform x:Name="OverlayContainerTransform"
                        X="{Binding ElementName=OverlayContainer, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                        Y="0"/>
  </Grid.RenderTransform>

  <ContentPresenter x:Name="OverlayContent" Content="{Binding Path=OverlayViewModel"/>

</Grid>
```

I can then dynamically set the *OverlayViewModel* property to various view models when needed and use data templates to get WPF to automatically display the correct view for the relevant view model:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ViewModels:AuthorisatonViewModel}">
    <Views:AuthorisatonView/>
</DataTemplate>
```

When I change my view model and slide on the overlay I set focus scope to the overlay focus scope (which I seem to be able to do OK with OverlayContainer.Focus), but the problem I'm having is that I can't seem to get keyboard focus to go to the first focusable element on the relevant view, whatever it may be.

I thought I'd found what I needed [here](http://julmar.com/blog/mark/?p=50) but when using this code to walk the visual tree it seems that when passing the ContentPresenter (*OverlayContent*) into VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount() that it returns no children, so it can't get down the elements within the dynamic view.

I've also tried setting the *OverlayContainer* as the active focus scope and then calling:

```
OverlayContainer.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next))
```

but that failed to work also.

All the views I am trying to display have at least 1 focusable, visible, enabled element in them.

Any ideas?

Comment: Perhaps try navigating the Visual Tree at a later [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) than `DispatcherPriority.Render`? There's a chance the controls aren't rendered yet when you're trying to set Focus, so this would give them time to Render first.

Comment: Yup that worked a treat - thank you very much :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears Rachel was spot one - it turned out it was that the view hadn't rendered yet, so the child visual elements weren't available yet. Calling my focuser like so:

```
// Focus on first child element only once rendered
this.OverlayContainer.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Render,
                                             new Action<FrameworkElement>(Focuser.FocusOnFirstFocusableChild),
                                             this.OverlayContainer);
```

allowed me to access all the child visual elements and set focus accordingly.